# Saving an element in local storage with JavaScript and Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frontend

I'm currently trying to create this Angular application, where you can "favourite" a business card into your local memory. I have having issues with actually pushing the `clicked` element onto the browser's local memory.

Plus in addition, I don't think I'm doing it in a very *Angular* way.

> Can you help me push a card onto the local memory by clicking the star
>   element? The element should change colour to yellow after it has been successfully pushed.

I've used several other questions as resources but most of them use additional modules such as `ngStorage`.

In case you use `ngStorage` or any other additional angular directive, can you please explain it so I actually get how it functions?

**Here is a Fiddle of the small application:** [Small Application](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/14681/)

Comment: your 'ng-click' isn't firing in your jsfiddle

Comment: Do you really need to save the element in `localStorage`? There are numerous issues with your fiddle, I've tried to solve them - [check if it works for you](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/14683/).

Comment: I have extended @StanislavKvitash answer to store fav emp in locaStorage. http://jsfiddle.net/ashgab/g96hmf04/2/

Comment: @Ashish your fiddle is not opening and Stanislav Kvitash's fiddle doesn't store my `clicks` in the local storage as I wanted to.

Comment: Can you please try this one? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashgab/g96hmf04/3/)

Comment: @Ashish the idea is to change the color to yellow whenever it's pushed to the localStorage. I'm not sure if it works since it doesn't change color thus when I refresh it, everything is the same.

Comment: @ZombieChowder check the newer version [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashgab/g96hmf04/3/)

Comment: @Ashish thes this one works perfectly, thanks you!

Comment: @ZombieChowder I just tried to fix the issues with your fiddle and code, also tried to show the more angular-way of manipulating styles and classes. Storing/getting values from `localStorage` is something that is well described over the web in different articles and tutorials :) That is why I just posted a comment and not an answer to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Install bower angular-local-storage

```
bower install angular-local-storage --save
```

Controller js like this

```
angular.module('tempApp', ['LocalStorageModule'])
  .controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope, $location, localStorageService) {
    console.log('DataCtrl');

    $scope.add = function() {
        localStorageService.set("msg", "hello world");
    }

  });
```

Refer this link [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did many things wrong, this code is not perfect but it's a good guide that does what you want.

For example you did not use $scope for the function saveStar, you used the id that belongs to all starts, you assigned localStorage.setItem instead of getItem to get the output var, etc

```
<div class= "well well-lg col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"  ng-repeat="person in employees | filter: searchBox">
            <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="star"
             ng-style="set_color(person.id)"
             ng-click="saveStar(person.id)"></i>
                <p>{{person.id}}</p>
                <p>{{person.name}}</p>
                <p>{{person.username}}</p>
        <p>{{person.email}}</p>
        <p>{{person.address.city}}</p>


            </div>
```

Look how look `ng-style="set_color(person.id)"` and `ng-click="saveStar(person.id)"`
Now check the controller

```
$scope.saveStar = function(e){      
    $scope.output = localStorage.getItem('localStar');
        localStorage.setItem('localStar', e); 
    $scope.$apply();
}   
  $scope.set_color = function (e) {  
  if ( e == $scope.output){
       return { color: '#ffd000' };
        }else{
            return { color: "red" };
        }

}
```

This way with double click it works.